# Java: How to check what object an instance belongs to?

Tags: java, arrays, object, instance, equals

So apologies if this question has been answered already, although I did have an extensive look but couldnt quite find the answer. To sum up the situation I am trying to create a simulator program that deals with different predator and prey creatures and currently have the issue of getting each creature to check what type of creature it is next to, which I would prefer to do checking if the instance belongs to the same object.

So say for example I did this:

```
private class Creature {
...
Creature [] fish = new Creature();
Creature [] shark = new Creature();
Creature [] penguin = new Creature();
}
```

and then created several instances (creatures) of each type in a loop like so:

```
for (int f=1;f<rnd;f++) {
fish[f] = new Creature();
//set attributes of creature
```

and then so the program can tell where they are located in relation to each other I created a grid system like so:

```
Creature [][] gridloc = new Creature[x][y]; //relates to number of spaces tiles that determines movement.
Creature [] crloc = new Creature[tc]; //stores a reference to all creatures created.
...

crloc[tc] = fish[f]; gridloc[x][y]=crloc[tc] //or fish[f]
}
```

Anyway to sum even tho I summarised the code there quite a lot, that all works but when getting each creature to check next to it in gridloc for what is there e.g. a predator I am unsure of a way to check if it finds another creature to determine if that is an instance of the same object type or a different one. So something like:

```
if (!gridloc[x][y].getObject().equals(gridloc[x+1][y].getObject()) //if the current creature is not the same as the one next to it.
```

I am aware of things like instanceof but that only works with checking if an object is an instance of a class, not if a instance belongs to the same type of object. I also can't simply use fish[1].equals(fish[2]) because they have different attributes and that would check if they are exactly the same.

Any ideas/suggestions would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: "Instance belonging to object" - Not getting the terms you're using. Object itself is an instance of the class.

Comment: Sorry yep you are right so in my situation: Creature is the class and fish, shark and penguin are instances of that class aka. objects. However I then create several instances of those objects and need to know if e.g. fish 1 is the same as fish 2 as it comes from the fish object but NOT the same as shark 1 as it comes from a different object.

Comment: What if you can use a boolean value in the class, for each Object, say penguin will set `isPenguin` to `true`, fish will set `isFish` to `true` or else you can use a `String` value, for each type of instance like `fish` will set this to `"fish"`, `penguin` to `"penguin"`. Not sure how good the approach is though. Or you can use an `enum` for this purpose

Comment: Thanks nIcE I think that approach would work but I would have to for example check for all other types of creatures a bit like: `if (gridloc[x+1][y].isPenguin() && ...isShark()` I would rather just check its not the same object type, tho may have to do it that way :) I have a similar way of doing that at the moment as each creature instance has a get/set method called setType/getType, which receives a string + iterator. I can then do `if (gridloc[x+1][y].getType().startsWith("Fish"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look into Polymorphism (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).  You declare a Creature as a base class (or interface) and extend/implement from Creature class for each type of a creature you have.  Each subclass will implement it's own methods to override Creature and allow you to correctly use the methods and also to detect the type using the class metadata that each instance will have.

Comment: Aah I remember polymorphism...you are quite right thx that would make more sense and make it easier to determine creature types etc. I am kind of relearning Java at the moment since the days of learning it at Uni :)

Answer (score 2):

It's an issue with your design. You have to create a Super class called Creature and sub classes for fish , penguin and all others. Then create the arrays with those sub class types. Then you can do the instanceof checks with your adjacent objects of the grid.

This design is based on Polymorphism. 
In the long run this is the best approach since code is more clean and structured. If you do this way, even after few years when you take a look at the code; still it will make sense.

Comment: So I guess no way of checking instanceof an object unless its a class. But then like you say I need to redesign it a bit like Alex said :)

Answer (score 2):

One option (and perhaps the best in the long run, see answers by @AlexC and @Don) would be to make subclasses of Creature, called Fish, Shark, Penguin etc.  Then you can use `instanceof`.

To combine that with polymorphism, you'd add a method `public boolean eats(Creature other)`  As an aside, when I helped babysit a 4 year old his favorite game with little plastic animal figures was "what eats what" with loud screams of delight.

1. In Creature, the code would be `return false;`  (though arguably fish eat fish?)
2. In Penguin, the code would be  `return other instanceof Fish;`
3. In Shark, the code would be `return true;`

Another option would be to have a field of Creature that describes it.  Maybe an enum, or a String for the latin classification names.  Then, you could use something like  `genus.equals("Carcharodon")` for Shark or `latinName.contains("Spheniscidae")` for Penguin.

Comment: Yep with polymorphism classes I should be able to do something like: `if (gridloc[x][y] instanceof Fish)` as fish would then be a class object. Currently all creatures have a setType and getType method, which receive/return a string + iterator e.g "Fish 3" to identify each one anyway :) This information along with its hunger level and age are displayed on the screen in an info box when you click on a creature.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe creature should be an enum...

```
public enum Creature {
    FISH(false), SHARK(true), PENGUIN(true);
    private boolean isPredator;
    private Point gridLocation;

    Creature(boolean isPredator) {
        this.isPredator = isPredator;
    }
    // ...getters/setters
}
```

with a separate world class for grid locations...

```
public class World {
    List<Creature> creatures = new LinkedList<>();

    public boolean isNearPredator(Creature c) {
        for (Creature i : creatures) {
            if (i.getGridLocation().distance(c.getGridLocation()) < 2
                    && i.isPredator()) {
                System.out.println("About to get eaten!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reasonable, but in the long run this may be tricky as he adds more and more creatures, wants to add the "Amazon Rain Forest Expansion Pack", etc...  Also, note that Penguin is both a predator (of Fish) and a prey (of Shark).

Comment: I agree this will cause problems down the line.

Comment: That would also be similar to me do something like `gridloc[x][y].getType().startsWith()` though I think? To be honest not got around to using enum much :) However I would like to start using the syntax sure with for loops, just cant quite get my head around how to do it at the moment :( Also u r correct Penguin would be both predator and prey so that will be another challenge :)